# How can I add a middle button in a UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UINavigationController that has its left and right button properties set. Instead of having the title in the middle, I want to put a button there. I'm not sure how I can achieve this.

CODE:

```
UIBarButtonItem* titleButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                        initWithTitle:symbol 
                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(addToWatchlistButtonClicked:)];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleButton;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use *titleView* property of *UINavigationItem*.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = button;
```

Comment: WARNING: Incompatible pointertypes UIView* from UIBarButtonItem* ends up crashing the app. See modified question with code.

Comment: Resolved. I can't add a UIBarButtonItem to a view, changed to UIButton and ish all good.

Comment: This is still broken !  (try plopping that code in and you'll see.)